# Conditional ordering in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Table `T`:

```
ID | Name | Days
```

`ID` is the PK.

I do want to `select * from T, order by ID descending`, but on TOP to be those entries which have the `ID` between `1000` and `1004`

```
select *
from T
order by Id descending // something like a *case*?
```

1004 - 1st / 1003 2nd / 1002 3rd / 1001 4th / 1000 5nd ... and then 6th should be the max Id, and after this all descending excepting the Ids between 1000 - 1004 which we already displayed on the TOP.

I would like to know also the linq statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (998), (999), (1000), (1001), (1002), (1003), (1004)) AS T(ID)
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN T.ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1004 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END
    , ID DESC;
```

Took sample data from [Sick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/sick)'s answer.

How does this work?

1. It checks whether your ID is matching your criteria and assign it a
   value of 1
2. Everything else will have 2
3. It will sort by this value first
4. Your IDs with matching criteria will ALWAYS come first
5. Then we sort leftovers by ID in DESC order

**Output:**

```
╔══════╗
║  ID  ║
╠══════╣
║ 1004 ║
║ 1003 ║
║ 1002 ║
║ 1001 ║
║ 1000 ║
║  999 ║
║  998 ║
╚══════╝
```

I've made additional example, which generates 676.800 rows in our DB:

```
;WITH TestTable (ID)
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.objects
    CROSS JOIN sys.schemas
    )
SELECT *
FROM TestTable AS T
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN T.ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1004 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END
    , ID DESC;
```

That's its result:

```
╔════════╗
║  ID    ║
╠════════╣
║ 1004   ║
║ 1003   ║
║ 1002   ║
║ 1001   ║
║ 1000   ║
║ 676800 ║
║ 676799 ║
║ 676798 ║
║ 676797 ║
║ 676796 ║
║ 676795 ║
║ ...    ║
║ 1006   ║
║ 1005   ║
║ 999    ║
║ 998    ║
║ ...    ║
║ 1      ║
╚════════╝
```

Comment: What if my table has 20k entries? You gave a particular fixed example containing 7 entries.

Comment: There's no difference as I can see. If your IDs match this criteria: `WHEN T.ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1004 THEN 1`, they will always come first in this query.

Comment: You are right, my fault, sorry. thanks for your informations

Comment: @FlorinM. I've updated my answer with better example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from T
order by case when ID between 1000 and 1004 then -100000 else id end,ID desc
```

Here `-100000` is s random low value

Example :

```
SELECT *
FROM   (VALUES (998),
               (999),
               (1000),
               (1001),
               (1002),
               (1003),
               (1004) ) tc (id)
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN ID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1004 THEN -100000
            ELSE id
          END,
          ID DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```